# RTL Tester plugin for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, right-to-left

I used this wordpress plugin to change the website directions from LTR to RTL

the plugin name is: RTL Tester: http://wordpress.org/plugins/rtl-tester/

The main problem is the website admin dashboard is in english and I dont want to change it to Arabic, but when I active the RTL Tester plugin, It will change the website front end pages directions .. (home .. about ... contact) .. and the wp-admin dashboard! and thats what I dont want to change ... I only want to change the website front end and not the back-end!

any one can help me?

Comment: This one

http://wordpress.org/plugins/rtl-tester/

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but give it a try:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Admin Fixed RTL */

add_filter( 'get_user_metadata', 'fix_rtl_so_18968615', 10, 4 );

function fix_rtl_so_18968615( $value, $object, $key, $single ) 
{
    if( !is_admin() )
        return $value;

    if( 'rtladminbar' == $key )
        return 'ltr';

    return $value;
}
```

This will intercept `get_user_meta` for the key [`rtladminbar`](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/rtl-tester/tags/1.0.4/rtl-tester.php), and if it is not the admin side, it returns the saved value, otherwise make it LTR for all users.

After clicking on RTL, the admin will change to RTL, but will come back to LTR in the next load.

Comment: Thank you! but can you tell me where I can use this code? since my knowledge in php is basic

Comment: That's a very simple plugin. Create a PHP file, upload to `wp-content/plugins/` folder and activate.

Comment: is there's anyway to edit the RTL plugin itself? and ask it to only RTL the front-end pages and keep the admin dashboard LTR?

Comment: Did you try to navigate to another page after switching directions?

Comment: Yup, its all the same!

Comment: Funny... it works in my test environment, but here's a modified version of the plugin that leaves the admin LTR: http://pastebin.com/K1TXYW74 (the mods are in lines 48 and 72)

Comment: Thats amazing! its worked now thank you veryyyy much :)

I just replaced the plugin code with the code that you provide me